# Gitlab repo file storage is not empty even after reverting repo to the first commit?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have reverted gitlab repo to the first commit hoping to reset the master branch to initial commit.

But even after doing that,Why is it 3.6GB files occupied?

I only have three commits, all of them are readme file initializations.

is there a way to clean up the storage?

[image]

```
From https://gitlab.com/x/x1.git
5bd41b5d4f3989ef373d73745f4db3151e2044b8    HEAD
5bd41b5d4f3989ef373d73745f4db3151e2044b8    refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Do you use soft reset or hard reset? if it's soft reset then gitlab storage won't be emptied

Comment: @ahmad_fauzan458 I used hard reset to the first commit

Comment: @ahmad_fauzan458 I even deleted master branch and re-created it, even then I still see that storage is occupied.

Comment: Run `git ls-remote` in the local repository and it prints all refs in the server repository. These refs refer to commits and commits refer to other objects that occupy storage space.

Comment: @ElpieKay I see two refs when I ran that command? How can I know which is occupying the space, how can I delete it? can you provide some help

Comment: @ElpieKay I updated the question with the output

Comment: @user_12 It has only `master`. If you clone a new repository, how mush storage does it take?

Comment: @ElpieKay Do you mean cloning my current repo?

Comment: @ElpieKay If I clone my repo, it's just 200 bytes or something.

Comment: The storage is supposed to get smaller after `git gc` is run by Gitlab. But I don't know when it's run or how it's manually triggered.

Comment: @ElpieKay Oh I see, I did ran the command `git gc` manually but I didn't see any changes. Everything was still the same